# Increment key name in multidimensional array with Jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to make "duplicate" option and I am using clone to do it.

I have multiple inputs like this:

```
name="items[id-1][recepti][1][name]"
name="items[id-1][recepti][1][media]"
```

When i click duplicate, it needs to clone and change to this:

```
name="items[id-1][recepti][2][name]"
name="items[id-1][recepti][2][media]"
```

This is my current code:

```
$(document).on("click",".duplicate_recept",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var copy      = $(this).closest(".recepti-dodaci").clone(); // clone
    var obrok_id  = $(this).closest(".ishrana").attr("data-id"); // this is key in [id-]
    var recept_id = $(this).closest(".recepti-dodaci").attr("receptid"); // this is current KEY after [recepti]
    var recept_count = sets_count(obrok_id,"recept") + 1; // this needs to be set after [recepti]
    copy.attr("id","recept_"+obrok_id+"_"+recept_count).attr("receptid",recept_count); // this works fine

    copy.find("input[name*='[recepti]["+recept_id+"]']").attr('name', function(_, name){
      return name.replace("input[name*='[recepti]["+recept_id+"]']", "input[name*='[recepti]["+recept_count+"]']")
    }); // this doesnt work

    $("#is-"+obrok_id+" .svi_recepti").append(copy);

  });
```

Comment: So , what doesn't work here ? Also , show your html code.

Comment: @Swati it won't find input and change key.

  <input type="text" name="items[id-1][recepti][2][naziv]" value="Test 123" required="" placeholder="Unesite naziv obroka" class="form-input naziv_ishrane">

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it, its really simple and I probably i was really tired

```
copy.find("input[name*='id-"+obrok_id+"']").attr('name', function(_, name){
  return name.replace('[id-'+obrok_id+'][recepti]['+recept_id+']', '[id-'+obrok_id+'][recepti]['+recept_count+']')
});
```